# padding-left for li doesn't seem to work in ITextSharp

Tags: html, itext

I am generating pdf using ITextSharp 5.5.8 by passing the html markup in a string.

I am trying to adjust the width between the bullet of the list item and text using `padding-left` css style. However, after generating the pdf, this doesn't seem to work when it works fine in html.

Here is how i want:

[Padding between bullet and text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjLjB.jpg)

Here is what i get currently :

[Currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOE9Q.jpg)

```css
 <style type="text/css"> html {
   font-family: Verdana;
   font-size: 10px;
 }
 h1,
 h2,
 h3 {
   font-family: Verdana;
   font-weight: bold;
 }
 h1 {
   font-size: 12px;
 }
 h2 {
   font-size: 11px;
 }
 h3 {
   font-size: 10px;
   position: relative;
   left: -20px;
 }
 ol li {
   padding-left: 10px;
 }
 </style>
```

```html
<li>
  Licensee Primary Contact Information
  <ol type="a">
    <li>Name: hkj</li>
    <li>Job Title: hkjhkjhkjh</li>
    <li>Mailing Address: kjhhkj</li>
    <li>
      Direct Telephone Number: hkjh</li>
    <li>Email Address: k</li>
    <li>Web Address: jhk
    </li>
  </ol>
</li>
```

Comment: Please post a jsfiddle too!

Comment: @Tewdyn I have added it.

Comment: Just add an padding-left to your <li> elements

Comment: You could try  `li{ text-indent: you_value; }`

Comment: @esteban, text-indent is not supported in ITextSharp. Please have a look at the link below
http://demo.itextsupport.com/xmlworker/itextdoc/CSS-conformance-list.htm

Comment: @Dotnetcoder, yes I got that, please look at the answer, it was eddited to maybe find a different solution using `margin-left` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```css
li{
text-indent: 125px;
}
```

```html
<li>
  Licensee Primary Contact Information
  <ol type="a">
    <li>Name: hkj</li>
    <li>Job Title: hkjhkjhkjh</li>
    <li>Mailing Address: kjhhkj</li>
    <li>
      Direct Telephone Number: hkjh</li>
    <li>Email Address: k</li>
    <li>Web Address: jhk
    </li>
  </ol>
</li>
```

A bit exagerated but just to make a point, the padding is to the whole `li` this includes the bullet,  so you have to use  `text-indent`

**EDIT**

Maybe a work around could be to insert a `div` as a child and  ad a `margin-left` to the child `div`:

```css
li .child{
margin-left: 120px;
}
```

```html
    <li>
      Licensee Primary Contact Information
      <ol type="a">
        <li>Name: hkj</li>
        <li>Job Title: hkjhkjhkjh</li>
        <li>Mailing Address: kjhhkj</li>
        <li><div class="child">Direct Telephone Number: hkjh</div></li>
        <li>Email Address: k</li>
        <li>Web Address: jhk
        </li>
        <li><div class="child">Direct Telephone Number: hkjh</div></li>
        <li><div class="child">Direct Telephone Number: hkjh</div></li>
      </ol>
    </li>
```

Comment: text-indent works in html but ITextSharp is not supporting it.

Comment: @Dotnetcoder, I eddited the answer, maybe it helps. GL